rosserial for control linear actuator
I’m currently working on a robotics project using ROS, and I'm encountering an issue with rosserial communication. My setup includes:

Teensy for publishing data from a JSN-SR04T sensor,
Arduino Nano for subscribing to data from ROS and sending it via RS485 to an SMC LE Motor Driver PA CN5 controlling a linear actuator.

Everything works well on the Teensy side, but during testing, I keep receiving the following error when running rosserial on Arduino Nano:
"Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino."
I’ve ensured that both rosserial versions are the same, checked baud rates, and confirmed that the hardware connections are stable. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions for troubleshooting?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
